# Como hacer un split sin tomar en cuenta las comas dentro de comillas hacia un array

Tags: c#, split

Tengo un split pero lo hace con comas dentro del split

```
string[] valores = linea.Split(",(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)");
```

lo habia intentado de esa manera como encontre en otras preguntas pero todo el texto queda contenido en la primera posicion como evito esto?

Quiero este texto

```
1,REMEDY Calazime Skin Protectant,"Adverse effect of amphetamines, subsequent encounter","Medline Industries, Inc.",$540.21,10
```

Quede en un array para introducirlo a una clase pero al hacer el split toma los de adentro de las comillas asi: 
https://gyazo.com/825776b216971c2547bf01e8ba6e9c42
De:
https://gyazo.com/fff085acf7aa420649125774d469fe8e

Comment: que quieres hacer y que necesitas agregar un texto referencia y la salida esperada!

Comment: Lo he editado no se si eso es lo que quieres

Comment: Es en c# mvc 6 en Visual 2017

Comment: El texto tiene siempre la misma forma? cual es tu resultado esperado para el split? el split no es siempre la solucion, muchas veces a mano (que es lo mismo que hace el split internamente) es mas facil, pero pone que resultado esperas y ejemplo de las cadenas de entrada. Tienen siempre el mismo formato?

Comment: Gracias a los 2 por su atencion encontre la respuesta en este foro pero no como la buscaba, es esta https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3507498/reading-csv-files-using-c-sharp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es posible que el patrón que estas buscando sea este: [`(?:"([^"]+)?"|([^,]+))`](https://regex101.com/r/urmp33/1), pruebalo:

```
var texto = @"1,REMEDY Calazime Skin Protectant,""Adverse effect of amphetamines, subsequent encounter"",""Medline Industries, Inc."",$540.21,10";
var patron = @"(?:""([^""]+)?""|([^,]+))";

foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(texto, patron))
{
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[0].Value);
}
```

El código anterior muestra la siguiente salida:

> ```
> REMEDY Calazime Skin Protectant
> "Adverse effect of amphetamines, subsequent encounter"
> "Medline Industries, Inc."
> $540.21
> 10
> ```

Comment: Como respondi en mis comentarios encontre la solucion en las respuestas de este https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3507498/reading-csv-files-using-c-sharp pero es basicamente lo mismo que tu pusiste, gracias por responder!